# How to Make an Online / Offline Phonegap Application

Tags: html, cordova

I am investigating using HTML5 for a new suite of mobile applications that our company will be writing.

I found this demo here,

http://phonegap.com/start#android

Which shows how to use eclipse to generate and run an android application which is written using HTML.

Just wondering whether there is any information around about writing an online / offline application? This application would collect data based on the user input, and that data would be sent off to a central server and put into our central SQL server database.

What mechanisms could be used to connect and send the data to the server for instance?

Another requirement would be that some data would have to be sent and cached on the device, data related to the tasks that the logged in user has to perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interact with your server by applying traditional javascript techniques, like ajax, or other cross-domain methods like jsonp, iframes, etc.

The HTML5 `localStorage` will help you saving data on the local device, it's very useful when your data can be expressed as strings. But if your app requires more powerful tool for local data management, you can make a phonegap plugin with native code for anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Offline-mode save the data in Local Storage which is feature of HTML 5. Whenever the user in Online Sync the data with the server. In case the data to be stored locally is quite large then use PhoneGap that allows to store some big stuffs 
[Ref.: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage].